# 2000s (or earlier) anime where the good guys try to reform bad guys with an amulet. Failure results in the enemy turning into trees

Tags: story-identification, anime

For almost two years, I've been looking for an anime with a group of bad guys who a group of good guys, led by a young man, are trying to turn into good guys by either convincing them or fighting them (I don't remember which). Each bad guy owns an amulet in the shape of a circle, added as an image below, probably, brown-like colored near their (his/her) neck. If they are successfully turned, the amulet decays. Otherwise, IIRC, they transform to trees or tree-like things.

The amulet look like this sketch:

[image: round amulet with two symmetrical droplets-like marks]

I watched it by 2005. However, the anime's production is highly likely prior to 2005. I watched it on TV, dubbed in Turkish, before going to school.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  Where?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: What was the name of the channel you saw this?

Comment: @myriaidee1sessh43 If I remember rightly, “Kanal D”

Comment: In this link it gives you a list of shows that were aired on that channel. You can try by looking up the shows that you think you saw the anime or cartoon by the years 
they give.  Good luck.  It might help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanal_D

Comment: @myriaidee1sessh43 the lists contain Turkish-products, not products dubbed or taken from other TV's. For example, I'm pretty sure Kenshin(Samurai X) was featured on the TV channel but it is not in the lists.

Comment: @myriaidee1sessh43 If you look at the list, you cannot found "Monster Rancher". But thanks for the way.

Comment: I don't know Turkish but you can look for the channel's history programs in Turkish, that's what I do to find old tv shows in channels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I beg your pardon if I cause you to lead wrong researches and my wrong remembrance but I've just found it. It is [*Monster Rancher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Rancher_(TV_series)) (1999-2001).

> The story follows a boy named Genki Sakura, who is a key player of the Monster Rancher video games. After winning a tournament hosted by the game's creators, Genki wins a special CD that he can use to unlock a special monster in his game at home. However, upon using this disk in his game console, he finds himself transported to a world of monsters that, much like Genki's game, are given life by scanning special stone disks within temples. There, he meets a girl named Holly, who is seeking a stone disk containing a legendary Phoenix that will save the land from the tyranny of an evil ruler named Moo. Upon attempting to use the disk Genki had won to try and release the monster, they bring forth a different sort of monster, which Genki names Mocchi. Wanting to free the land from Moo's rule, Genki, Holly, Mocchi and their other monster companions go on a quest to find the stone disk that contains the Phoenix.

The amulet I remembered is,

[image: horned creature with amulet used as cloak button]
[image: red creature also using the amulet as a cloak button of sorts]
[image: white horned wolf-like creature with a mane]

I found it because I remembered the boy’s cap, the girl, and the blue-white wolf, respectively, when I was searching on Google  for Kanal D animes or Türkiyede ki animeler.

Comment: Ah. How did you find it? You can still self-accept tomorrow.

Comment: @I remembered the boy’s cap, the girl and the bluewhite wolf, respectively when I was searching on google Kanal D animes or Türkiyede ki animeler.